# How to use empty layout from controller?

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

It's my **execute** method from **controller**:

```
$this->_view->loadLayout();
$this->_view->renderLayout();
```

It's my **layout** inside the <**page**>:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block
            class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
            name="printshipment_index_index"
            template="Module_PrintShipment::print_shipment.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

In this case I have default **Magento layout** with header, footer etc. And I need fully empty page. I have tried to add

```
<update handle="empty"/>
```

but then my block doesn't appear. What can you advise me?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `content` container in an `empty` layout by default.
Try this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="root">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="printshipment_index_index" template="Module_PrintShipment::print_shipment.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: As of Magento 2.4.2 an empty layout page can come with 150+ useless dependencies/extra network requests (if no merging/bundling is enabled). =/

Answer (score 2):

In your Controller Class, you need to add "true" when creating your factory under the "execute" function.

To assist you further; I include my code below to help writing this Class:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $PageFactory;

    public function __construct
    (
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        , \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $Encoder
        , \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $PageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->PageFactory = $PageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       $resultPage = $this->PageFactory->create(true);
       return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Notice the (true) bit here to do this:

> $resultPage = $this->PageFactory->create(true);

Works for me, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `empty` layout then you can pass this on [`<page>`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/5d572a023720bee054aba89c48ae50e9ba006942/app/code/Magento/Shipping/view/frontend/layout/shipping_tracking_popup.xml#L8) tag, for example

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="printshipment_index_index" template="Module_PrintShipment::print_shipment.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow default `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/print.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="printshipment_index_index"          template="Module_PrintShipment::print_shipment.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

or you can use simply

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="print" />
    <body>
          <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="printshipment_index_index"          template="Module_PrintShipment::print_shipment.phtml"/>
          </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can we use `layout="empty"` ?

Comment: @KeyurShah yes we can use `layout="empty"` too.

Comment: Unfortunately, with your method, as well as with layout="empty", my .phpml file is not rendered(( It is OK when layout isn't empty.

Comment: @Skorzhyk i checked this code it is working with custom luma and blank theme.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the "default" layout handles being applied you may need to use this in your controller execute function:

```
$this->_view->loadLayout(false);

return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers here but more thorough

I did it with layout XML

https://github.com/DominicWatts/MaintenancePage/blob/master/view/frontend/layout/maintenance_page_mode.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="empty" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
        <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <remove src="requirejs/require.js"/>
        <remove src="css/styles-l.css"/>
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <remove src="css/styles-s.css"/>
        <remove src="css/print.css"/>
        <remove src="requirejs/require.js"/>
        <remove src="mage/requirejs/mixins.js"/>
        <remove src="requirejs-config.js"/>
        <remove src="mage/polyfill.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="translate" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="requirejs-config" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="root">
            <block class="Xigen\MaintenancePage\Block\Page\Mode" name="page.mode" template="Xigen_MaintenancePage::page/mode.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```